# Apache Ignite CLI to store key value pair

Tags: database, command-line, ignite

Is there any way I could use the Apache Ignite's visor CLI to store the key value on the server itself via command line?

Answer (score 1):

Visor CLI is for monitoring and management purposes.
It doesn't provide means for inserting new data. Yet it allows reading data and clearing caches.

Comment: Is there any way I can write the data via command line?
Also, How can i read the data using Visor CLI

Comment: You could use [REST API](https://apacheignite.readme.io/v2.3/docs/rest-api#put) and call it from the command line via CURL.  
To enable REST API you need to add `ignite-rest-http` library to the classpath.

Comment: @DeepakMehra You can read cache contents using cache -scan command in Visor CLI. Run "help cache" command in Visor for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There open issue in Ignite JIRA: [IGNITE-6976](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-6976)
You can track this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can call Ignite Rest API, eg. `http://host:port/ignite?cmd=put&key=newKey&val=newValue&cacheName=partionedCach`

More detail: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#put